# Why isn't my PHP contact form working at all?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've tested my site's mailing with a different script - just to make sure it wasn't the host, and it's working fine.

I'm not sure why my code isn't working. I've included all my contact forums code except the html. It seems to not be loading the php, as it doesn't show any error messages when I put in an invalid email etc. - it just refreshes the page it seems.

Help is much appreciated, thanks everyone.

```
 <!-- Contact Form Js -->
  <script type="text/javascript">                                 
    // contact form js
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "inc/contact-process.php",
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
      // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
      if(msg == 'OK') {
          result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>';
          $("#fields").hide();
          setTimeout("location.reload(true);",7000);
      } else {
          result = msg;
      }
      $('#note').html(result);
    }
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
   </script>   
   <!-- End Contact -->
```

**PHP - 'contact-processes'**

```
<?php
/*
Credits: Bit Repository
URL: http://www.bitrepository.com/
*/

include dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/config.php';

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
include 'functions.php';

$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
$message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);


$error = '';

// Check name

if(!$name)
{
$error .= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
}

// Check email

if(!$email)
{
$error .= 'Please enter an e-mail address.<br />';
}

if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
{
$error .= 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.<br />';
}

// Check message (length)

if(!$message || strlen($message) < 15)
{
$error .= "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.<br />";
}


if(!$error)
{
ini_set("sendmail_from", WEBMASTER_EMAIL); // for windows server
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
     "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
    ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());


if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}
else
{
echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
}

}
?>
```

PHP - 'functions'

```
<?php
function ValidateEmail($value)
{
    $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

    if($value == '') { 
        return false;
    } else {
        $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $value);
    }

    return empty($string) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

PHP - 'config'

```
<?php
define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", 'snip@myemail.com');
?>
```

Comment: Check your functions.php file. Where it is located. You have given contact-process file path as follows `inc/contact-process.php` so in that file include finds the path in inc folder for function.php, if it will not there, then there will be a warning given by the PHP. to check the warning write following line at the TOP of the `contact-process.php`  LINE: `ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);`

Comment: What is the value of str that is posted?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` means to report everything except notice. use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` instead

Comment: @user3540050 I added that, and I'm not getting any errors or anything. Should `include 'functions.php';` be `inc/functions.php'` instead?

Comment: `function.php` file must have in inc folder. And write is same as you have written for config.php

Comment: This comment wont help. But are you sure you have email protocol configured. Or is this testing on Live server with smtp. or Localhost?